# iOS 8: Black screen gap between Splash screen

Tags: ios, ios8, splash-screen

I installed the iOS8 beta, and now it seems that between my splashscreen and the presentation of my rootviewcontroller there is a gap of a couple of secs. in which the whole screen in black.

I read somewhere that it could be just that I'm assigning my viewController to the rootViewController too late, but I changed that and now assign it in the init method. I;m out of ideas and any help would be great.

Comment: It's a bug that only occurs (at least for me) when the debugger ia attached.

Comment: @HAS, It happens for me in production too

Comment: Where do you assign the root view controller?

Comment: In the app delegate, directly to the navigation controller... Like a gangster